# IOHIDEventSystemCreate on iOS6 failed

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, iokit

IOHIDEventSystemCreate always return NULL on iOS6 (work fine on iOS5). 
Anyone know why?

[Example on iPhoneDevWiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOHIDFamily)

```
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDEventSystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void handle_event (void* target, void* refcon, IOHIDServiceRef service, IOHIDEventRef event) {
  // handle the events here.
  printf("Received event of type %2d from service %p.\n", IOHIDEventGetType(event), service);
}

int main () {
  // Create and open an event system.
  IOHIDEventSystemRef system = IOHIDEventSystemCreate(NULL);
  IOHIDEventSystemOpen(system, handle_event, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  printf("HID Event system should now be running. Hit enter to quit any time.\n");
  getchar();

  IOHIDEventSystemClose(system, NULL);
  CFRelease(system);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it doesn't work on iOS6 for me too.
I now use this:

```
void *system = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(system, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback(system, handle_event, NULL, NULL);
CFRunLoopRun();
```

But I don't know why it only reports multitouch+keyboard events.
SpringBoard in iOS6 calls this:

```
IOHIDEventSystemClientSetMatchingMultiple(system, array);
```

with an array containing PrimaryUsagePage + PrimaryUsage, but I can't get it working...
If someone knows a solution for getting accelerometer events for example, I'm interested too.

Comment: I am getting  'IOKit/hid/IOHIDEventSystem.h' file not found. Any idea what am i missing

Answer (score -1):

you can change headers like #include "IOHIDEventSystem.h" when you drag IOKit.framework to your project

Comment: Actually, please remove this answer. This should be a comment on the other answer. But, this is a 5 year old question, so it's likely not relevant today.