# IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, iokit

I'm trying to get touch events in my application. So I used the IOHIDFamily callback to get the events.  My code is like this:

```
void handle_event(void* target, void* refcon, IOHIDServiceRef service, IOHIDEventRef event)
{
    printf("Received event of type %2d from service %p.\n", 
           IOHIDEventGetType(event), service);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    void *ioHIDEventSystem = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(system, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback(system, handle_event, NULL, NULL);
    CFRunLoopRun();
}
```

I got an error when executing:

> IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(system, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
>
> IOKit`IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop:
> ...
> 0x32f8fd14:  cmp.w  r10, #0
> 0x32f8fd18:  strd   r10, r11, [r4, #116]      <---EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN)
> 0x32f8fd1c:  beq    0x32f8fdac                ; IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop + 168
> 0x32f8fd1e:  ldr    r1, [r4, #96]
> 0x32f8fd20:  cbz    r1, 0x32f8fd2a            ; IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop + 38
> 0x32f8fd22:  mov    r0, r10
> ...

Did I use IOHIDFamily in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least a couple problems I see in the code posted:

First, you are calling

```
CFRunLoopRun();
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method, which is going to be called on the main/UI thread.  I see no reason for that, so just remove that line.  I'd normally expect to see that call if you had a method that you were running on a background thread, and you needed to start a background run loop.  Or, if you were registering for callbacks directly in `main()`, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15118510/119114).

Then, you have this:

```
void *ioHIDEventSystem = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(system, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

I'm guessing the second line should be

```
IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(ioHIDEventSystem, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

I don't know what the `system` variable actually refers to, but it doesn't look right.

Take a [look at this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550916/119114), as it seems to use **IOKit** correctly.