# IOS 7 touch notifications

Tags: objective-c, iphone, jailbreak, ios7.1, iphone-privateapi

I want to receive x, y coordinates of a touch. I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550916), but it doesn't seem to work for IOS 7. I get the following error:

> Tweak.xm:96:2: error: no matching function for call to
>         'IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop'
>           IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(ioHIDEventSystem, CFRu...
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /home/agiera/theosprojects/phoneit/theos/include/IOKit/hid/IOHIDEventSystemClient.h:72:7: note: 
>         candidate function not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type
>         'void *' to 'IOHIDEventSystemClientRef' (aka '__IOHIDEventSystemClient *')
>           void IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(IOHIDEventSystemC...
>                ^
>   Tweak.xm:97:2: error: no matching function for call to
>         'IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback'
>           IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback(ioHIDEventSystem, ha...
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /home/agiera/theosprojects/phoneit/theos/include/IOKit/hid/IOHIDEventSystemClient.h:68:7: note: 
>         candidate function not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type
>         'void *' to 'IOHIDEventSystemClientRef' (aka '__IOHIDEventSystemClient *')
>           void IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback(IOHIDEventSyste...
>                ^
>   2 errors generated.

Is there an updated implementation or another means to get this functionality for IOS 7?

edit:

code:

```
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDEventSystem.h>
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDEventSystemClient.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Touch Events
void handle_event (void* target, void* refcon, IOHIDServiceRef service, IOHIDEventRef event) {
    NSLog(@"handle_event : %d", IOHIDEventGetType(event));
    if (IOHIDEventGetType(event)==kIOHIDEventTypeDigitizer){
        IOHIDFloat x=IOHIDEventGetFloatValue(event, (IOHIDEventField)kIOHIDEventFieldDigitizerX);
        IOHIDFloat y=IOHIDEventGetFloatValue(event, (IOHIDEventField)kIOHIDEventFieldDigitizerY);
        NSLog(@" x %f : y %f", x, y);
    }
}

static void initTouchEventHandling() {
    void *ioHIDEventSystem = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

    IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(ioHIDEventSystem, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback(ioHIDEventSystem, handle_event, NULL, NULL);
    IOHIDEventSystemClientUnregisterEventCallback(ioHIDEventSystem, handle_event, NULL, NULL);
    IOHIDEventSystemClientUnscheduleWithRunLoop(ioHIDEventSystem, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
}
```

initTouchEventHandling is called in my constructor. I added IOKit to my private frame works and implemented this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23650095/2089636).

edit2:

I think there is something wrong with the way I am adding the IOKit framework. I tried swapping it for an older version and got the same errors. Then I tried deleting it altogether and got the same errors. Maybe someone can correct something in my makefile:

```
ARCHS = armv7 arm64
TARGET = iphone:clang:latest:7.0

export THEOS_DEVICE_IP = 192.168.1.104

include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = phoneit
phoneit_FILES = Tweak.xm
phoneit_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit QuartzCore
phoneit_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = IOKit

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
SUBPROJECTS += prefs
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/aggregate.mk
```

Comment: Can you post the code on how you are getting the coordinates. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15633639/334091 check this too

Comment: I got the same error using that. Do you think replacing my iokit with an xcode 4 version might fix this? There are know issues with the iokit from xcode 5, but not to specific to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this in `initTouchEventHandling()` :

```
static void initTouchEventHandling() {

    IOHIDEventSystemClientRef ioHIDEventSystem = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

    IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(ioHIDEventSystem, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback(ioHIDEventSystem, (IOHIDEventSystemClientEventCallback)handle_event, NULL, NULL);

    //add other custom code...
}
```

This method works for me. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Would you post an example makefile and imports? And maybe also your source of header files? My compiler doesn't recognize those classes.

Answer (score -1):

You have two ways to get the user touch location:

1- Using `touchesBegan` method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  // Get the specific point that was touched
  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
  NSLog(@"X location: %f", point.x);
  NSLog(@"Y Location: %f",point.y);

}
```

2- Using `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userTapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I should have been more clear though. I'm making a cydiasubstrate tweak and I wanted to get touch location from anywhere including lockscreen and keyboard. I there a system image view I could attach the gesture recognizer to or a class I could hook the touchesBegan method into that wouldn't mess things up? Thanks